# ". . . , mostly for fear of what might be revealed if such direct dialog were allowed."

Tags: prepositional-phrases, supplementation

I ran across this sentence while googling; is it meaningful and grammatical?

> . . . , mostly for fear of what might be revealed if such direct dialog were allowed.

#### update

I have particular difficulty understanding this part:

> mostly for fear of what

There appears to be no subject (noun).

Comment: I think it is grammatical. Is there some part of the sentence you are uncertain about?

Comment: @Wim Lewis yes I have, especially this part. "mostly for fear of what" I have hard time to understand it. I think there in no subject(noun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a sentence but merely a preposition phrase (PP) modifying the main clause of a sentence:

> Many EDA companies keep their R&D engineers focused on product development and bug fixing, shielding them from any and all direct contact with end-users, mostly for fear of what might be revealed if such direct dialog were allowed.

- The core of the PP, *for fear* means “out of fear” or “because of fear” ... EDA companies keep their engineers focused on product development and bug fixing ***because they are afraid of `something`***.
- This PP is modified by the adverb *mostly*: the EDA companies have other reasons, but the main reason is *for fear*.
- The noun *fear* takes a complement expressed as a PP headed by *of*, which names the thing which is feared—the ***`something`*** which the EDA companies are afraid ***of***.
- That ***`something`*** is *what might be revealed*. This is a *free relative clause* (or *fused relative clause*) in which *what* is a pronoun standing for the subject of the verb *might be revealed*. What is it? We don't know, and the author isn't going to tell us—it's ‘hidden’ behind the pronoun. All we know is that the EDA companies are afraid that ***`something`*** might be revealed.
- But that ***`something`*** might be revealed only ***if*** direct dialog [between the engineers and end-users] were allowed.

So we paraphrase:

> If R&D engineers were allowed to speak directly with end-users they might reveal ***`something`*** which EDA companies don't want end-users to know. That is the main reason why the companies shield their engineers from direct contact with end-users, and keep them focused on product development and bug fixes.